# Has been +adj/n - the time frame

Tags: grammar

I have a bit of confusion regarding "sb/sth. has/have been adjective./noun". For example, "I have been ill." "This festival has been great." "He has been a smart person." I am wondering about the time frame of them; I am not sure whether they mean "I have been ill in the past and I am still ill now"/"This festival is great from the past to the present"/"He was a smart person and still is", or "I was ill in the past but I have recovered now"/"This festival was great but now it's over or no longer great"/"He was smart but now is not".

I have consulted Google but there are many versions of explanations and I am a bit lost.

Comment: The meaning of the present perfect is 'underspecified' and interpreted by context. You may find [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32) useful, especially §[3.2 Pragmatic meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Comment: @StoneyB I have read this page but it doesn't contain information about when the verb is a stative verb like "be"

Comment: To further clarify, I know about the construction "have been + noun + for/since". But in London I have heard people using this construction without any time clauses at all. That's why I am wondering.

Comment: A PrPf may be continuative, resultative, or experiential, but **you cannot know which** any particular instance is without access to the larger discourse in which it occurs. The aspect of the main verb supplies some context, but it is not determinative. All perfects are 'stative by construction'.

Comment: What do you mean by "stative by construction"? But certainly when the verb is stative the usage is a bit different right? Because I read that stative verbs don't take progressive forms when expressing the stative meaning, even when the state is temporary.

Comment: W e l l ... we have been drifting for a couple of centuries toward wider use of progressive statives -- "I'm loving it!". 'Stative by construction' means that a perfect or progressive construction entails a stative interpretation, regardless of the default lexical aspect of the lexical verb. But exactly **what** state a perfect construction expresses is determined by context.

Comment: @StoneyB I have read that there are some stative verbs that can take progressive forms even when intending the stative meaning(I have been wanting it for so long.) But I am not sure about love/like, because from this link there is a counter-example: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect. (We do not normally use the present perfect continuous with stative verbs. We use the present perfect simple instead: I've always (been liking x) liked John.) I am not sure about the "stative by construction" you are talking about

Comment: because I was taught that perfect can mean finished action or state that has/had begun, so there's two types of perfect. But I have seen that there's an article about this that you cited in that page and I will have a read when I am free (so I can better understand what you mean but feel free to clarify for me).

Comment: You have to be very careful in consulting standard references like dictionaries on highly technical matters -- they're apt to be a couple generations or more behind 'state of the art'. *Perfect* is a term with a complex history: in Latin it meant (more or less) 'completed action', and the perfect constructions with *HAVE* and *BE* in *most* European languages have retained that meaning -- *but not all, and certainly not  **English!** where uses of the perfect have been evolving continuously since it was introduced ten or twelve hundred years ago. Down to the early years of the 20th century ...

Comment: ... English grammarians never caught up with the evolution; we're getting closer today, but the language is still evolving.

Comment: @StoneyB If in English "have been" doesn't retained the meaning of "completed action", what would it mean then? That's what I am concerned about. Because if I don't know the meaning of it I cannot use it or understand it. For some sentences with context I can understand because words like "but I have recovered now", "I wish I could get better soon" indicates the time frame, but like I said... I have encountered the bare sentence where the context is not enough for me to judge so I would have to look at the sentence on its merit. I would be interested in knowing...

Comment: what people usually mean when saying the type of sentence in this thread. And... regarding the last example that you offered, you said the present perfect is appropriate in that sentence. But that sentence doesn't indicate the sequence of two things in the past, which I read was what past perfect essentially means... Also about your second last example, yes it means the person has stopped being an inspiration at the time being talked about, but then would it mean the person recently just stopped being an inspiration (but then there are certain results now, for example we really admire him?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have been ill**

This sentence means that he was ill  some time ago and is ill now  and may not be well for some time in the future too.

> **He has been a smart person.**

He has been a smart person since I knew him.He will continue to be so.

> **He has been a great inspiration for 
>   me**

His effect was on me in the past and in the present and may be in the future too.

But the meaning of each sentence depends on the context.The context is more important.

Comment: I see. So this would normally means that the thing being talked about happened in the past and continues to the present. "I have been ill" means I entered the state of being ill in the past and am still waiting for recovery.

Comment: Yes. you are.I have recovered.That is different

Comment: **I have been ill** leaves open the question of whether the person concerned is still ill, is recovering or has recovered. It is not specific. As StoneyB notes, the meaning depends on the context.

Comment: And "He has been a smart person, but not since his stroke" and "He has been a great inspiration, and may be so again after he serves his sentence".

Comment: @There are many shades of meanings for such sentences.The context is more important.

Comment: @StoneyB Just wondering, if the action had stopped when he had a stroke, shouldn't the sentence be like "He had been..."?

Comment: @RonaldSole I can understand what you mean. But I have seen people just throwing out the sentence without time clauses or other information. "You have been very responsible for sure." How do I know the time frame he is talking about? (PS I feel that if the person is recovering he is still ill, just less than before)

Comment: @user103302 You **don't** know from the bare PrPf by itself. You only know from the discourse context. ... In real life, as opposed to textbooks, utterances are always embedded in a discourse context.

Comment: @user103302 And with regard to your "he had been" question -- No. There are circumstances in which the PrPf may be appropriate. For instance, you say *I can't see giving X the Great Intellect Award. He's stupid.* ... to which I reply *Ah, but he **has been** a smart person. That's what we're giving him the award for.*

Comment: @StoneyB For your first reply, I was saying "I just felt that I needed to be responsible so I tell all of them about the fact", and then the reply. Is he saying "you were very responsible"? Is he saying "you are always responsible from the past to the present"? Although which meaning it is doesn't affect the communication, I am still wondering. Because when you say something you intend some meaning with your words.    For your second reply, I feel that if you say "he has been a smart person" it kind of implies the state continues to the present. Because accroding to the page you gave me,

Comment: "More than 80% were governed by a ‘presumption-of-persistence’ rule: hearers assume that “states that they have been told about persist until they are given evidence to the contrary”. Also the Oxford Dictionary explanation of "perfect" is "denoting a completed action or a state or habitual action which began in the past." So if it began in the past it sounds like it's still happening now, or at least that's how I understand it. If it's open to many interpretations, then that leaves open the problem: what interpretation should I adhere to when I say it(use it)?

Comment: Because it's impossible that when I say it, I take into consideration every context that affects its meaning. I say it at the moment when I am constructing that particular sentence.. not sure if that makes sense.